# Associative table - QuerySyntaxException: Userapp is not mapped - hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

My Tools :

- Netbeans 8.x
- Hibernate plugin
- PHP my admin

I have 3 tables :

`User` ->>- many to many ->>- `Userapp` ->>- many to many ->>- `Application`

User have :

- userId
- userName

UserApp :

- userId

  -applicationId

Applicaiton :

- applicationId
- applicaitonName

HQL Query :

```
SELECT a.applicaitonName
FROM Userapp ua
    LEFT JOIN Application a On ua.applicationId= a.applicationId
WHERE
    ua.userId = ?
```

Error :

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Userapp is not mapped [SELECT a.applicaitonName
FROM Userapp ua
    LEFT JOIN Application a On ua.applicationId= a.applicationId
WHERE
    ua.userId = 1]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:120)
```

How I proceeded :

- I created hibernate.cfg.xml
- I created hibernate.reveng.xml
- I created Hibernate Mapping Files and Pojors from database

When I create Hibernate Mapping Files and Pojors from database, it created 2 news object : `Application` and `User`. But not `Userapp` ...

do I have to create it manually ?

Here the hibernate.reveng.xml :

```
<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
  <schema-selection match-catalog="allin"/>
  <table-filter match-name="user"/>
  <table-filter match-name="application"/>
  <table-filter match-name="userapp"/>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

Thanks for your help !!

Comment: HQL and SQL are different languages. Learn the language That's not how you create joins in HQL. And check your case: Userapp != UserApp.

Comment: ok thanks, but the main problem is still the same. Why my associative table is not mapped

Comment: HQL uses entities, not tables. Learn HQL. You don't have any UserApp entity, so no wonder you get that exception. I also guess that you don't have a many-to-many association between User and UserApp, but between User and Application. UserApp is just a join table that is used to contain this association. Really, you need to learn Hibernate associations and HQL. The simple fact that you ask about a HQL query without even mentioning the entities you have shows that you're missing the fundamentals.